# cmake error, poco was not found, Raspberry Pi, ROS Indigo

Tags: ros, catkin, raspberrypi, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm new to ROS and having trouble trying to install everything on an RPI.

I'm following this link here - http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Indigo%20on%20Raspberry%20Pi

I'm up to 2.3 Building the catkin Workspace, and when running the command "sudo ./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release --install-space /opt/ros/indigo" I get the following error:

CMake Error at /opt/ros/indigo/share/cmake_modules/cmake/Modules/FindPoco.cmake:186

Messgae reads: Poco was not found. Set the Poco_INCLUDE_DIR cmake cache entry to the top-level directories. E.g /usr/local/include or c:\poco\include\poco-1.3.2

I don't want to start messing about with obscure files looking for something as it's taken several days to get to this point and i don't want to start over if i can avoid it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/204532/cmake-error,-poco-was-not-found,--raspberry-pi,-ros-indigo/) by [Ben12345](https://answers.ros.org/users/21811/ben12345/) on ROS Answers with karma: 98 on 2015-03-09

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [miguel](https://answers.ros.org/users/21658/miguel/) on 2015-06-27**:
I get the same error on my Pi, Did you perhaps figure it out?

**Comment by [Ben12345](https://answers.ros.org/users/21811/ben12345/) on 2015-06-28**:
Hi, no sorry i didn't. I used beagle bone black instead. Moved on to using an intel based fanless computer running full desktop ubuntu. Makes life a lot easier. I have got a a raspberry pi 2 now, will try again. You can run the arm ubuntu on the new pi, ROS jade has arm ubuntu, should be all current

**Comment by [Ben12345](https://answers.ros.org/users/21811/ben12345/) on 2015-06-28**:
commenting system has a character limit - i think the issue was the raspberry pi distro changing so much. The new jade ROS came out a few weeks ago, ARM ubuntu is not run by the pi foundation so should be more stable for want of a better word. it's also a proper OS, not a hacked one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We had a similar issue while setting up an rPi 2 on wheezy. The solution that worked for us was to download the poco c++ library from [POCO C++ Project](http://pocoproject.org/download/index.html) and follow the instructions listed [here](https://github.com/andreasmuller/openframeWorks-Raspberry-PI/tree/master/LIBS/poco-1.4.3p1). The instructions seem very detailed for various systems but we only verified it worked on the linux system for rPi. This solved our issues regarding POCO.

---

Originally posted by [ATXCyborg](https://answers.ros.org/users/22725/atxcyborg/) with karma: 18 on 2015-11-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`sudo apt-get install libpoco-dev`

---

Originally posted by [mtbrobotanist](https://answers.ros.org/users/26344/mtbrobotanist/) with karma: 76 on 2016-09-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6